# How to append each element from a loop to a newly created <a> tag, but in a way so that each element ends up in a separate anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I have this markup(current) and below that the desired markup(goal) that I would like to get.

It should be done via JavaScript, so no HTML editing.

Started with a "for loop" for singling out the individual card, created a  tag that I need, and gave it a class, but I simply have no idea how to add each card to a separate anchor tag.

Is it also supposed to go through some loop or?

```js
const programCards = document.querySelectorAll('.program-card'),
  aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('class', 'card-link');

for (let i = 0; i < programCards.length; i++) {
  const card = programCards[i];

  card.outerHTML = aTag;
}
```

```html
<!-- Current -->
<div class="section-frame grid-container">
  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="">
    <p>lorem dorem porem</p>
  </div>

  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="">
    <p>lorem dorem porem</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Goal -->
<div class="section-frame grid-container">
  <a class="card-link" href="#">
    <div class="program-card">
      <h4>title</h4>
      <img class="card-image" src="">
      <p>lorem dorem porem</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="card-link" href="#">
    <div class="program-card">
      <h4>title</h4>
      <img class="card-image" src="">
      <p>lorem dorem porem</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the `programCards` NodeList with the `forEach` method and append each card to the created `aTag` using the `appendChild` method after which you can then append the `aTag` to the parent div `.section-frame`.

```js
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('.section-frame');
const programCards = document.querySelectorAll('.program-card');
programCards.forEach(card => {
  let aTag = document.createElement('a');
  aTag.setAttribute('class', 'card-link');
  aTag.appendChild(card);
  parentDiv.appendChild(aTag);
});
```

```html
<div class="section-frame grid-container">
  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="">
    <p>lorem dorem porem</p>
  </div>

  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="">
    <p>lorem dorem porem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand. So you create an a tag inside for each method so it would be created for each card separately instead of putting it outside the scope like I did. Thanks. Always feel embarrassed when I see the solution. :D